# Is it safe to replace a CPU in MacBook Pro 15” 2018?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, repair

My MacBook Pro 15” 2018 stopped working. The CPU model is:

> 2.6GHz 6‑core 8th‑generation Intel Core i7 processor, Turbo Boost up to 4.3GHz

I brought it to official Apple Service. They didn’t tell me what got broken, they just said in order to repair it I need to replace a logic board.

I brought my MacBook to another unofficial service. They found that the CPU got damaged. They changed the CPU and my MacBook Pro works now. And it is cheaper than the official Apple Service wanted to charge my for the new logic board. My Mac is still at the service shop, I’m gonna collect it from the service shop this week.

My question, is it safe to replace a CPU only? I heard that Macs can break again and a better option is to replace a logic board entirely. Is this true? Does anybody have anything to say about it?

Comment: If you mac is still at the service shop, how can you take it there this week? Seens confused, please get the story clear.

Comment: He wrote that he was going to "take it this week", not "take it there this week". I read this as meaning that he is going to collect the Mac this week.

Comment: @solar-mike Yes, exactly, I’m going to collect it from the service shop this week.

Comment: I would have pressed Apple to fix a hardware fault in a 2-year-old machine, which they should do under statutory consumer laws in most countries. (Depends where you are, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "safe" exactly. Replacing a CPU is in itself safe in terms of not inherently creating any new risk of damaging the computer, or creating safety risks for the user.

However the tech must take care to replace the CPU in the correct manner (i.e. you need to handle it properly without damaging the new CPU), and you need to replace the CPU with the same model (i.e. replacing the CPU with a higher wattage CPU is not a good idea).

Note that if the CPU was damaged due to a problem with the logic board itself (for example if it was damaged by an overvoltage caused by a logic board problem) - then you are ofcourse still at risk of damaging the new CPU also.